# Why does Chrome install itself under user directory instead of Program files?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

On Windows 7 (x64), Chrome is installed in:

```
 C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\
```

Is that better that Program Files? Is it a general best practice?

I suppose it's good (and more secure) to allow each user to have a separate app, but I'm surprised there isn't a `C:\Users\userid\Program Files\` directory for that, like on Mac OS X.

Comment: *> Why does Chrome install itself under user directory instead of Program files?* I’ve been futilely asking myself this question for the past 20 years.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's so that Google can update the Chrome without asking for administrator privileges. 
Which, depending on your view can make it more secure or less.

Generally this is really not a best practice as much as it is a developer's decision. Historically developers didn't do it to save space on the disk but that's a moot point nowadays.

Comment: I think this decision was almost certainly made to try to reduce severe cases of PEBKAC from hindering Chrome's adoption by (l)users.

Comment: @Doc It's more the existence of IE than anything that's hindering the adoption of Chrome.

Comment: Naw, it's more the existence of ignorance than IE.

Comment: Problem In Chair Not In Computer PICNIC error.

Comment: That explanation is supported by the presence of old_chrome.exe in the same directory.

Comment: Maybe a moot point in your mind.